# R summarise does not remove duplicates from join result

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I'm trying to join two tables in r but end up with several duplicates despite my summarise().

[example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhAgO.png)

notes:
I've tried right, left, and inner joins

```
#periodsForPredict is a 20x1 tibble
#workfile is a much larger dataset that contains duplicates of timeSeq&period with other unique data. 

workfile %>%
    mutate(period=as.character(period)) %>%
    right_join(periodsForPredict, by='timeSeq') %>%
    select(timeSeq, period) %>%
    summarise(timeSeq, period)
```

**Is there a reason why my summarise does not remove duplicate groupings?**

Thanks in advance !

Comment: 1. Don't add screenshots of code/data. We cannot copy/paste it into our R session to test it. Use `dput` to share data. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). on how to do that. 2. `summarise` does not remove duplicates, perhaps you are looking for `distinct` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `summarize` verb calculates aggregates after you `group_by()`. Here is an example of the proper use of summarize.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(x = rep(c("Ag", "Ag", "Be", "Be", "Mo", "Mo"),2),
              y = rep(c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B"),2))
df1 %>% 
  group_by(x, y) %>%
  summarize(count = n())
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   x [3]
  x     y     count
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 Ag    A         2
2 Ag    B         2
3 Be    A         2
4 Be    B         2
5 Mo    A         2
6 Mo    B         2
```

You can remove duplicates with `distinct()` from `dplyr` or for simple tasks `unique()` from `base` works, too.

```
df1 %>%
  distinct()
   x y
1 Ag A
2 Ag B
3 Be A
4 Be B
5 Mo A
6 Mo B

df1 %>%
  unique()
   x y
1 Ag A
2 Ag B
3 Be A
4 Be B
5 Mo A
6 Mo B
```

Comment: Distinct() is what I was looking for. Thanks!